# VS code snippets not showing on ctrl+space (but user-defined do)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I have an issue with VS Code snippets. I've seen a bunch of questions opened about user-defined snippets, but in my case those work: it's the default ones the ones I'm missing. I'm running the latest VS Code with the latest C/C++ extension by MS, in Windows.
I'm interested specifically in C/C++ snippets. As far as I know, the official C/C++ extension includes them [since May](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/05/08/visual-studio-code-cc-extension-may-2018-update-intellisense-configuration-just-got-so-much-easier/). I set them to appear on top of the suggestions, so it's easier for me to see them, but I can only see my personal ones:

[image]

Any ideas why? Am I missing setting something up?

Comment: Did you save your file with a proper extension?

Comment: In the gif I attached, I was working on a new, unsaved file, but I correctly set the language to C, and my user-defined C snippets appear when I ctrl+space. Thanks for the suggestion, though, it's a common oversight.
I tried in .c files and .h files where the language is autodetected to C, and the behaviour is the same. The reason I made my example with a new file was to avoid making it to visually noisy. Changed the title to make it (hopefully) more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by uninstalling the c/c++ extension from Microsoft. I guess the update went wrong and didn't add the snippets to whatever VS Code uses to look for snippets. After uninstalling the extension and reinstalling, I can confirm it works again.

PS: I had to uninstall the Arduino extension in the process, as it depends on the C/C++ extension. Didn't bother to reinstall it as I barely use it, but I can't confirm if that had an impact or not. If just reinstalling doesn't work and you also have the Arduino extension, you might want to try without it.